# A single letter insert or delete function

Tags: python

Write a function named single_insert_or_delete that accepts two strings as input arguments and returns:

0 if the two strings match exactly.
1 if the first string can become the same as the second string by inserting or deleting a single character. Notice that inserting and deleting a character is not the same as replacing a character.
2 otherwise

[image: Problem statement]

thats what i reached so far

```
def single_insert_or_delete (word1,word2):
    word1=word1.lower()
    word2=word2.lower()
    limit=min(len(word1),len(word2))
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    common=[]
    if word1==word2:
        return 0
    for i in range(0,len(word1)):
        list1.append(word1[i])
    for k in range(0,len(word2)):
        list2.append(word2[k])
    if abs(len(word1)-len(word2))==1:
        for c in range(0,limit+1):
            if list1[c]==list2[c] or list1[c]==list2[c+1] or   list1[c+1]==list2[c]:
                return 1
            else:
                return 2
    else:
         return 2
```

It actually works good but if you tried tricky words like 'the' and 'that' it will give 1 instead of 2 which is wrong

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question and describe your problam *as text*. An image is not acceptable as a question.

Comment: can you post some test cases for this method; i'm having a hard time trying to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: oh , click on the frist couple of line which are blue to open the picture of the problem

Comment: Try to retype the problem description instead of provide a link. Some users are unable to follow/view the image links

Comment: @MahmoodHatemMito No, an image is not a question.

Comment: Write a function named single_insert_or_delete that accepts two strings as input arguments and returns:

0 if the two strings match exactly.
1 if the first string can become the same as the second string by inserting or deleting a single character. Notice that inserting and deleting a character is not the same as replacing a character.
2 otherwise

Comment: @MahmoodHatemMito Please [edit] your question and ask the question there. Don't use comments for this.

Comment: @Tichodroma ok i have done that now , can you see it ?

Comment: I think you have some out-of-bounds access there, consider if `word1` is the empty string and `word2` is some single letter. There's no valid index for `word1`.

Comment: So like Levenshtein distance, but limited to 2?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe well you are very right, but how can that help solving this?

Comment: @fafl i am actually a beginner so i am not aware of Levenshtein distance theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to return outside the for loop and recheck the comparison logic in if.

for c in range(0,limit+1):

```
        if (list1[c]==list2[c] or list1[c]==list2[c+1] or list1[c+1]==list2[c]):
              return 1
```

The problem here is, when the words(the and this) are compared, it satisfies the first condition of t being equal to t and it enters the if condition where it returns 1 and exits the function. It will not proceed with the for loop.

If you want something similar rather than difflib, you may also use the following code.

```
import numpy


def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):

    s1 = s1.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()

    l1 = [i for i in s1] # convert the string into an array
    l2 = [j for j in s2] # convert the second string in an array

    if s1 == s2:
        flag = 0

    elif abs(len(s1)-len(s2)) == 1:
        if len(l2) > len(l1):
            l1,l2 = l2,l1
        l3 = list(numpy.in1d(l1,l2)) 
    # This will compare the elements of 2 arrays and return bool values based on the match

        if l3.count(False) > 1: # count the number of false values
            flag = 2
        else:
            flag = 1
    else:
        flag = 2

    return flag


print "Output-1 ", single_insert_or_delete("book","boot")
print "Output-2 ", single_insert_or_delete("Java","Python")
print "Output-3 ", single_insert_or_delete("dog","Dog")
print "Output-4 ", single_insert_or_delete("sin","sink")
print "Output-5 ", single_insert_or_delete("programming","programing")
```

Output :

C:\Python27\python.exe D:/Python/Mylist.py

Output-1  2

Output-2  2

Output-3  0

Output-4  1

Output-5  1

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: mmmm, yeah you are absolutely right, so my algorithm needs some fix

thanks alot  bro :)

Comment: What is the fix exactly?

Comment: I thought you were just looking for the problem. If I was you, I would definitely use difflib just as suggested by @mhawke .Thats pretty simple and gets the job done with minimum loc.

Comment: @KaranThakkar . Edited with updated working code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to work out *how* to do it, or whether you just want to solve it, but if the latter you could use [`difflib.ndiff()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff):

```
from difflib import ndiff

def single_insert_or_delete(word1, word2):
    change_count = sum(1 for s in ndiff(word1.lower(), word2.lower()) if (s[0] == '-' or s[0] == '+'))
    if change_count > 1:
        return 2
    return change_count

word_pairs = [('Python', 'Java'), ('book', 'boot'), ('sin', 'sink'), ('dog', 'Dog'), ('poke', 'spoke'), ('poker', 'poke'), ('programing', 'programming')]

for pair in word_pairs:
    print('{}: {}'.format(single_insert_or_delete(*pair), pair))
```

**Output**

```
2: ('Python', 'Java')
2: ('book', 'boot')
1: ('sin', 'sink')
0: ('dog', 'Dog')
1: ('poke', 'spoke')
1: ('poker', 'poke')
1: ('programing', 'programming')
```

Comment: OMG, Actually i am a beginner i have just started learning this couple of weeks ago , so i am not familiar with difflib package but you definitely nailed it :)

i just wanted to know whats wrong with my algorithem

Comment: @MahmoodHatemMito: if you just wanted to know what is wrong with your algorithm then you probably should not accept this answer :) This answer shows another way of doing with the standard library - it's interesting, but perhaps not what you wanted. Note that you did not actually ask a question at all :)

Comment: @MahmoodHatemMito: .... you may wish to replace the acceptance with an upvote instead.

Comment: i still cant vote unfortunately , its my first day in this site